# Blackberry Custom ButtonField

Tags: blackberry, focus, buttonfield

[This](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/normalax.png/) is default look when i launch activity.

After i play around with the wheel track pad then become like [this](http://imageshack.us/f/10/afterj.png/). The button image or whole button lost.

Here is my custom buttonfield which `extends ButtonField`.

```
public class Custom_ButtonField extends ButtonField {
Bitmap mNormal;
Bitmap mFocused;
Bitmap mActive;

int mWidth;
int mHeight;

public Custom_ButtonField(Bitmap normal, Bitmap focused, 
    Bitmap active) {
    super(CONSUME_CLICK);
    mNormal = normal;
    mFocused = focused;
    mActive = active;
    mWidth = mNormal.getWidth();
    mHeight = mNormal.getHeight();
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setBorder(BorderFactory
                    .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE, BorderFactory
                    .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
            bitmap = mNormal;
            break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
            bitmap = mFocused;
            break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
            bitmap = mActive;
            break;
    default:
            bitmap = mNormal;
    }
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                    bitmap, 0, 0);
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
}
}
```

Comment: Set a debug pointer on the `paint` method, check the `bitmap` before `drawBitmap`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a button with an image so you might be better off using the [Advanced UI Library](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI) published by RIM. Take a look at the `BitmapButtonField` class.

Answer (score 0):

Set Focusable on constructor.

```
super(Field.FOCUSABLE);
```